# C++ Graphics and Audio Libraries

Tags: c++, graphics, audio

I'm trying to find some good C++ Graphics/Audio Libraries. I have tried searching this site but the only answers I can find is "X library is the best library ever."  It gives me no information about the library except some link to some obscure site with the obscure library which also has little information about the library.

What I want instead is for people to tell me about each library's:

**Efficiency:**  Does the library run slowly with little memory? quickly with high memory?  Will it cause my programs to have a 2 gigabyte file size?

**Usability:** How long does it take to learn the library and how hard is it to use the library?

**Compatibility:** Does it play nice with other libraries?  Does it work in C as well as in C++?

**Operating System:** What operating system(s) does it run on?  Don't limit yourself to portable libraries.

**Forewarnings:** Is there something that tripped you up learning this library?

**Method of Communication** Do I list every pixel, do I tell it to render a model in an external file, or do I just tell it to render a circle?  Or for audio, do I tell it to give me a sin wave, a pattern of different wave forms, or just a .mp3?

**Features:** What features does the library have?

**License:** Does the library have any licenses or restrictions attributed to its use?

**Tutorials:** Where can I go to learn it?

I hope it isn't too picky to ask for all this information, this is my first question on Stack Overflow (and I have caused confusion merely by bad writing).  I don't mind if most of the text is copied from the library website, as long as the answer tells me as much of this information as possible up front.

Comment: I'd suggest you limit the scope of your question a little bit, e.g. do you want 3D graphics? 2D? Audio Synthesis? Audio Decoding? .... Also, will any of these libraries need to work with a specific platform? thank you.

Comment: The problem is that what I want isn't just 2d graphics or just 3d graphics or just audio synthesis or just audio decoding.  What I really want to do is to develop skills using multiple libraries.  I could probably ask "how do I make x application with y and z" but the problem is that the number of x's, y's, and z's is too vast for me to even want to ask that.  My worst fear with this question is that it feels like everyone wants to tell me about one library with y and z best for problem x, but nobody will tell me "Here are several unique libraries."  I really want to look at every option.

Answer (score 4):

I think you would probably like the libraries in the [Cinder project](http://libcinder.org/)

Answer (score 3):

All the cool kids use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). Quite a few of your questions are answered on its front page.

Comment: I think you'd also like Cinder ;) the "even cooler" kids are all using it.

Comment: @slomojo: I just read the "Why C++" section in the FAQ (since it's written in C++), and it just left a bad taste in my mouth. It sounds more like marketing than actual reasoning.

Comment: yes, the front face is pretty hyperbolic, but it's a very good set of tools, don't let the hype put you off... why read marketing copy when you can look at the code.